# Can't get past SIM PIN screen on Lumia 1520 after installing Windows 10 preview

Tags: insider-preview, lock-screen, glance, nokia-lumia-1520

A new build of *Windows 10 for Phones* was [released yesterday](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/04/10/new-windows-10-technical-preview-build-now-available-for-phones/). I've just enabled the '[Fast testers](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/03/19/next-windows-10-preview.aspx)' option through [Windows Insider](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/windows-insider/ed2b1421-6414-4544-bd8d-06d58ee402a5?signin=true) and after around 20 minutes it finished installing and restarted.

After it finished booting, it shows the 'Enter SIM PIN' screen. When I entered this and clicked 'Done', the screen just froze and nothing happened until the [glance screen](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/glance-screen/106e0a97-8b19-42cf-8879-a8ed2598fcbb) appeared.

The clock on the glance screen moves every now and then like normal behavior, but pressing any button or any combination of them doesn't have any affect. The only thing that works is keeping them all pressed until it restarts but then the same problems occur and I can't get past the SIM PIN screen.

Comment: When I remove the SIM card I can enter my phone password and it logs in just fine, but when I put it back in again and restart it the same thing happens.

Comment: Wonder if somehow a PIN was set on the SIM. Can you put this SIM into a different phone and check if it still requires a PIN? Also put a different SIM into this phone to check as well

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The sim pincode screen is NOT working. It seems to have changed. Instead of Enter there is an OK button and the input is not shown.

By placing the sim card in turned on mode I can pass by the Sim Pincode screen!

Answer (score 2):

The SIM PIN screen is currently broken. So far the only fix I've found, is to remove the PIN code altogether. You can bypass the SIM screen by pressing the "back" button when you start up the phone. If you do try to enter the pin code and enter it, the phone will freeze and you will need to reset it to access the phone Again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cellular, then settings and then change PIN. After that, you can turn PIN off, so you don't have to deal with it anymore.

Comment: If you go to Cellular and change pin, you still get the enter PIN-screen. This must be done on a different phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I performed a hard reset and it is working for me now.

Answer (score -2):

Turn off SIM PIN (I did it in previous handset). After doing so, phone won't present PIN entry screen.

Comment: You didn't provide a way to solve OP question. You just answered how to avoid SIM PIN to be asked.